# DataContractJsonSerializer dynamic object deserialization

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I would like to go with DataContractJsonSerializer instead of any third party libs like Json.NET I need to deserialize Json stream which can be one of my C# classes, and I dont know which one it is what i want to do is Deserialize json data -> determine type of this object -> do something with deserialized object according to type of this object. Is there anything to do with DataContractJsonSerializer.KnownTypes Property? Im really new to json.

Answer (score 0):

> what i want to do is Deserialize json data -> determine type of this object -> do something with deserialized object according to type of this object. Is there anything to do with DataContractJsonSerializer.KnownTypes Property?

Yes, it is related to the known types. Firstly, you need to specify the type you want to de-serialize in the constructor function. Then you can specify the types may be present in may be present in the object graph.

[DataContractJsonSerializer Constructor (Type, IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908209(v=vs.110).aspx)

But I still recommend you using the JSON.NET which will be easier than DataContractJsonSerializer, and the performance is even better. In ASP.NET Web API, JSON.NET is the default JSON serializer.

Answer (score 0):

or JavaScriptSerializer

```
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(strRet);
                StringBuilder sbErr = new StringBuilder(string.Format("{0} ({1}): {2}", rep.StatusDescription, dict["code"], Environment.NewLine));
                if ((dict["errors"] is Dictionary<string, dynamic>)) {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> item in dict["errors"]) { 
                        sbErr.AppendFormat("{0}=", item.Key);
                        foreach (string item2 in item.Value)
                            sbErr.AppendFormat("{0}. ", item2);
                    }
                }
```